# Python Bluez GATT server - client cannot disconnect

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, bluez, bluetooth-gatt

I've been working on a simple bluetooth GATT server app working on a Raspberry pi 3 model B. This app uses Bluez (version 5.49) to advertise services and characteristics. The app is based on the following example: https://github.com/Jumperr-labs/python-gatt-server

So far I have almost ended the server: clients can read and write in characteristics and services are advertised. The problem appears when the clients attempt to disconnect to the server. The server seems to be rejecting disconnections so the client cannot disconnect. The only way that one can disconnect a client is either shutting down the server or disabling the bluetooth adapter on the client.

The client is a Xamarin app using the following bluetooth library: https://github.com/aritchie/bluetoothle . Client issues have been discarded because the problem also apprears testing with bluetooth le testing apps like LightBlue (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lightblue-explorer/id557428110?mt=8).

The base GATT server is the following:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import dbus
import dbus.exceptions
import dbus.mainloop.glib
import dbus.service
import array
try:
    from gi.repository import GObject
except ImportError:
    import gobject as GObject
import advertising
import gatt_server
import argparse

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-a', '--adapter-name', type=str, help='Adapter name', default='')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    adapter_name = args.adapter_name
    dbus.mainloop.glib.DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
    bus = dbus.SystemBus()
    mainloop = GObject.MainLoop()
    advertising.advertising_main(mainloop, bus, adapter_name)
    gatt_server.gatt_server_main(mainloop, bus, adapter_name)
    mainloop.run()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In advertising:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import dbus
import dbus.exceptions
import dbus.mainloop.glib
import dbus.service
import functools
import exceptions
import adapters

BLUEZ_SERVICE_NAME = 'org.bluez'
LE_ADVERTISING_MANAGER_IFACE = 'org.bluez.LEAdvertisingManager1'
DBUS_OM_IFACE = 'org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager'
DBUS_PROP_IFACE = 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties'
LE_ADVERTISEMENT_IFACE = 'org.bluez.LEAdvertisement1'

class Advertisement(dbus.service.Object):
    PATH_BASE = '/org/bluez/example/advertisement'
    def __init__(self, bus, index, advertising_type):
        self.path = self.PATH_BASE + str(index)
        self.bus = bus
        self.ad_type = advertising_type
        self.service_uuids = None
        self.manufacturer_data = None
        self.solicit_uuids = None
        self.service_data = None
        self.include_tx_power = None
        dbus.service.Object.__init__(self, bus, self.path)
    def get_properties(self):
        properties = dict()
        properties['Type'] = self.ad_type
        if self.service_uuids is not None:
            properties['ServiceUUIDs'] = dbus.Array(self.service_uuids,
                                                signature='s')
        if self.solicit_uuids is not None:
            properties['SolicitUUIDs'] = dbus.Array(self.solicit_uuids,
                                                signature='s')
        if self.manufacturer_data is not None:
            properties['ManufacturerData'] = dbus.Dictionary(
            self.manufacturer_data, signature='qv')
        if self.service_data is not None:
            properties['ServiceData'] = dbus.Dictionary(self.service_data,
                                                    signature='sv')
        if self.include_tx_power is not None:
            properties['IncludeTxPower'] = dbus.Boolean(self.include_tx_power)
        return {LE_ADVERTISEMENT_IFACE: properties}
    def get_path(self):
        return dbus.ObjectPath(self.path)
    def add_service_uuid(self, uuid):
        if not self.service_uuids:
            self.service_uuids = []
        self.service_uuids.append(uuid)
    def add_solicit_uuid(self, uuid):
        if not self.solicit_uuids:
            self.solicit_uuids = []
        self.solicit_uuids.append(uuid)
    def add_manufacturer_data(self, manuf_code, data):
        if not self.manufacturer_data:
            self.manufacturer_data = dbus.Dictionary({}, signature='qv')
        self.manufacturer_data[manuf_code] = dbus.Array(data, signature='y')
    def add_service_data(self, uuid, data):
        if not self.service_data:
            self.service_data = dbus.Dictionary({}, signature='sv')
        self.service_data[uuid] = dbus.Array(data, signature='y')
    @dbus.service.method(DBUS_PROP_IFACE,
                     in_signature='s',
                     out_signature='a{sv}')
    def GetAll(self, interface):
        print('GetAll')
        if interface != LE_ADVERTISEMENT_IFACE:
            raise exceptions.InvalidArgsException()
        print('returning props')
        return self.get_properties()[LE_ADVERTISEMENT_IFACE]
    @dbus.service.method(LE_ADVERTISEMENT_IFACE,
                     in_signature='',
                     out_signature='')
    def Release(self):
        print('%s: Released!' % self.path)
    def __del__(self):
        self.remove_from_connection()

class TestAdvertisement(Advertisement):
    def __init__(self, bus, index):
        Advertisement.__init__(self, bus, index, 'peripheral')
        self.add_service_uuid('b5fd')
        self.add_service_uuid('dfe8')
        self.add_service_uuid('8ce1')
        self.add_manufacturer_data(0xffff, [0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04])
        self.add_service_data('9999', [0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04])
        self.include_tx_power = True 

def register_ad_cb():
    print('Advertisement registered')
def register_ad_error_cb(mainloop, error):
    print('Failed to register advertisement: ' + str(error))
    mainloop.quit()
def advertising_main(mainloop, bus, adapter_name):
    adapter = adapters.find_adapter(bus, LE_ADVERTISING_MANAGER_IFACE, adapter_name)
    print('adapter: %s' % (adapter,))
    if not adapter:
        raise Exception('LEAdvertisingManager1 interface not found')
    adapter_props = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object(BLUEZ_SERVICE_NAME, adapter),
                               "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties")
    adapter_props.Set("org.bluez.Adapter1", "Powered", dbus.Boolean(0))
    adapter_props.Set("org.bluez.Adapter1", "Powered", dbus.Boolean(1))
    ad_manager = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object(BLUEZ_SERVICE_NAME, adapter),
                            LE_ADVERTISING_MANAGER_IFACE)
    test_advertisement = TestAdvertisement(bus, 0)
    ad_manager.RegisterAdvertisement(test_advertisement.get_path(), {},
                                 reply_handler=register_ad_cb,                                 
    error_handler=functools.partial(register_ad_error_cb, mainloop))
```

In gatt_server:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import dbus
import dbus.exceptions
import dbus.mainloop.glib
import dbus.service
import array
import functools
import configreadwrite
import startstoprestart
import wlanconfig
try:
    from gi.repository import GObject
except ImportError:
    import gobject as GObject
from random import randint
import exceptions
import adapters

BLUEZ_SERVICE_NAME = 'org.bluez'
LE_ADVERTISING_MANAGER_IFACE = 'org.bluez.LEAdvertisingManager1'
DBUS_OM_IFACE = 'org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager'
DBUS_PROP_IFACE = 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties'
LE_ADVERTISEMENT_IFACE = 'org.bluez.LEAdvertisement1'
GATT_MANAGER_IFACE = 'org.bluez.GattManager1'
GATT_SERVICE_IFACE = 'org.bluez.GattService1'
GATT_CHRC_IFACE =    'org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1'
GATT_DESC_IFACE =    'org.bluez.GattDescriptor1'

class Application(dbus.service.Object):
    """
    org.bluez.GattApplication1 interface implementation
    """
    def __init__(self, bus):
        self.path = '/'
        self.services = []
        dbus.service.Object.__init__(self, bus, self.path)
        self.add_service(ConfigurationService(bus,0))
        self.add_service(StartStopRestartService(bus,1))
        self.add_service(WlanConfigService(bus,2))
    def get_path(self):
        return dbus.ObjectPath(self.path)
    def add_service(self, service):
        self.services.append(service)
    @dbus.service.method(DBUS_OM_IFACE, out_signature='a{oa{sa{sv}}}')
    def GetManagedObjects(self):
        response = {}
        print('GetManagedObjects')
        for service in self.services:
            response[service.get_path()] = service.get_properties()
            chrcs = service.get_characteristics()
            for chrc in chrcs:
                response[chrc.get_path()] = chrc.get_properties()
                descs = chrc.get_descriptors()
                for desc in descs:
                    response[desc.get_path()] = desc.get_properties()
        return response
    def __del__(self):
        self.remove_from_connection()

class Service(dbus.service.Object):
    """
    org.bluez.GattService1 interface implementation
    """
    PATH_BASE = '/org/bluez/example/service'
    def __init__(self, bus, index, uuid, primary):
        self.path = self.PATH_BASE + str(index)
        self.bus = bus
        self.uuid = uuid
        self.primary = primary
        self.characteristics = []
        dbus.service.Object.__init__(self, bus, self.path)
    def get_properties(self):
        return {
                GATT_SERVICE_IFACE: {
                        'UUID': self.uuid,
                        'Primary': self.primary,
                        'Characteristics': dbus.Array(
                                self.get_characteristic_paths(),
                                signature='o')
                }
        }
    def get_path(self):
        return dbus.ObjectPath(self.path)
    def add_characteristic(self, characteristic):
        self.characteristics.append(characteristic)
    def get_characteristic_paths(self):
        result = []
        for chrc in self.characteristics:
            result.append(chrc.get_path())
        return result
    def get_characteristics(self):
        return self.characteristics
    @dbus.service.method(DBUS_PROP_IFACE,
                        in_signature='s',
                        out_signature='a{sv}')
    def GetAll(self, interface):
        if interface != GATT_SERVICE_IFACE:
            raise exceptions.InvalidArgsException()

        return self.get_properties()[GATT_SERVICE_IFACE]

class Characteristic(dbus.service.Object):
    """
    org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1 interface implementation
    """
    def __init__(self, bus, index, uuid, flags, service):
        self.path = service.path + '/char' + str(index)
        self.bus = bus
        self.uuid = uuid
        self.service = service
        self.flags = flags
        self.descriptors = []
        dbus.service.Object.__init__(self, bus, self.path)
    def get_properties(self):
        return {
                GATT_CHRC_IFACE: {
                        'Service': self.service.get_path(),
                        'UUID': self.uuid,
                        'Flags': self.flags,
                        'Descriptors': dbus.Array(
                                self.get_descriptor_paths(),
                                signature='o')
                }
        }
    def get_path(self):
        return dbus.ObjectPath(self.path)
    @dbus.service.method(DBUS_PROP_IFACE,
                        in_signature='s',
                        out_signature='a{sv}')
    def GetAll(self, interface):
        if interface != GATT_CHRC_IFACE:
            raise exceptions.InvalidArgsException()
        return self.get_properties()[GATT_CHRC_IFACE]
    @dbus.service.method(GATT_CHRC_IFACE,
                        in_signature='a{sv}',
                        out_signature='ay')
    def ReadValue(self, options):
        print('Default ReadValue called, returning error')
        raise exceptions.NotSupportedException()
    @dbus.service.method(GATT_CHRC_IFACE, in_signature='aya{sv}')
    def WriteValue(self, value, options):
        print('Default WriteValue called, returning error')
        raise exceptions.NotSupportedException()
    @dbus.service.method(GATT_CHRC_IFACE)
    def StartNotify(self):
        print('Default StartNotify called, returning error')
        raise exceptions.NotSupportedException()
    @dbus.service.method(GATT_CHRC_IFACE)
    def StopNotify(self):
        print('Default StopNotify called, returning error')
        raise exceptions.NotSupportedException()
    @dbus.service.signal(DBUS_PROP_IFACE,
                        signature='sa{sv}as')
    def PropertiesChanged(self, interface, changed, invalidated):
        pass
```

(...) Services and characteristic implementation (...)

```
def register_app_cb():
    print('GATT application registered')
def register_app_error_cb(mainloop, error):
    print('Failed to register application: ' + str(error))
    mainloop.quit()
def gatt_server_main(mainloop, bus, adapter_name):
    adapter = adapters.find_adapter(bus, GATT_MANAGER_IFACE, adapter_name)
    if not adapter:
        raise Exception('GattManager1 interface not found')
    service_manager = dbus.Interface(
            bus.get_object(BLUEZ_SERVICE_NAME, adapter),
            GATT_MANAGER_IFACE)
    app = Application(bus)
    print('Registering GATT application...')
    service_manager.RegisterApplication(app.get_path(), {},
                                    reply_handler=register_app_cb,
                                    error_handler=functools.partial(register_app_error_cb, mainloop))
```

And finally in adapter:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import dbus
import dbus.exceptions
import dbus.mainloop.glib
import dbus.service

BLUEZ_SERVICE_NAME = 'org.bluez'
LE_ADVERTISING_MANAGER_IFACE = 'org.bluez.LEAdvertisingManager1'
DBUS_OM_IFACE = 'org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager'
DBUS_PROP_IFACE = 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties'
LE_ADVERTISEMENT_IFACE = 'org.bluez.LEAdvertisement1'
GATT_MANAGER_IFACE = 'org.bluez.GattManager1'
GATT_SERVICE_IFACE = 'org.bluez.GattService1'
GATT_CHRC_IFACE =    'org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1'
GATT_DESC_IFACE =    'org.bluez.GattDescriptor1'

def find_adapter(bus, adapter_interface_name, adapter_name):
    remote_om = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object(BLUEZ_SERVICE_NAME, '/'), DBUS_OM_IFACE)
    objects = remote_om.GetManagedObjects()
    for o, props in objects.items():
        print('checking adapter %s, keys: %s' % (o, props.keys()))
        if adapter_interface_name in props.keys():
            print('found adapter %s' % (o,))
            if '/' + adapter_name in o:
                print('returning adapter %s' % (o,))
                return o
    return None
```

Any suggestion is accepted. I've been working this bug for some weeks now and I'm getting frustrated

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am facing the same situation right now.